# Cloud Optimization without capacity i.e. predict capacity needed

Tags: optaplanner

I have a problem where I have to predict the capacity needed in bin packing. For example how many big bags are required to fit the given number of items subject to given hard constraints.

From the documentation, I see that I need to specify the ValueRangeProvider but that is something which I don't have to start with. I want to predict that. Should I play with the smallest value and keep on increasing it until I get a solution with no violation of hard constraint or is there a different way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You want the whole subject of optimization distilled into a SO answer?

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear, what I meant was that if I don't specify @ValueRangeProvider but would like a optimum solution. How can I do that in Optaplanner as there is nothing in the documentation regarding that.

Comment: Edit the question. Sounds like you have a MUCH more specific question than what you have written would indicate!

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Balancing example more or less does that: there are 100 computers for example, but only a subset of those are actually used. The trouble is probably that you don't know how to populate that value range set.

You can't avoid not defining the value range - OptaPlanner can't invent values for you (how would it know how to construct them?).

In the 7.0.0.Beta1 documentation, take a look at **Overconstrainted planning with virtual values**. (That approach work for 6.4 too but isn't documented there yet.) That explains how to create that value range and enforce that OptaPlanner uses a little of those as possible.